# Como fazer upload de arquivos usando o Selenium WebDriver em Java

Tags: java, upload, selenium-webdriver

Alguém pode me ajudar comoo fazer upload de um arquivo usando o Selenium pelo código Java?

Eu fiz o código abaixo:

```
firefoxDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@ng-model='picFile']"));
aP.selecionarArquivo(dir+"C:\\Users\\Imagens\\tela.jpg");

public void selecionarArquivo(String path) throws InterruptedException 
{

    WebElement fileInput = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
    fileInput.sendKeys(path);
}
```

Ele não apresenta erro, porém não anexa o arquivo. Ele chega a preencher o campo do nome do arquivo como se tivesse anexado, porém não habilita(O botão somente é habilitado quando anexado um arquivo) o botão de Confirmar.

Comment: Encontrei o meu problema. Era o caminho do arquivo que estava errado. Eu achava que ao colocar um caminho errado apresentava alguma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Talvez valha a pena usar `os.path.isfile` antes de chamar o selenium para colocar o arquivo, já que você disse que ele não falha.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço o upload desta forma.
Se você conseguiu uma forma de fazer usando o seu método, melhor ainda!

```java
//UPLOAD ARQUIVO
        navegador.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ctl00_placeHolderMain_mainWebCad_upArquivofile0\"]"))
                .sendKeys("C:"+ File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"servflex050"
                        +File.separator+"Desktop"+File.separator+"2 - Ciclo 2_Roteiro de Teste"
                        +File.separator+"Arquivos_Importacao"+File.separator+"BRTPREV_ARQUIVO_REPASSE_072019_v2.txt");
```